# ¿Alguien sabe que formato de fecha es esta yyyy-mm-dd:hh:ss+??:?

Tags: c#, datetime, .net-core

Estoy teniendo problema al convertir un string a datetime, el problema es por el formato que me recibo (no puedo cambiar lo que recibo porque me lo manda una tercera empresa):

2020-10-22:18:30+18:30

He conseguido que la conversión funcione haciendo previamente un  split:

```
        string test = "2020-11-05:21:38+21:38";

        var test2 = test.Split("+");

        DateTime test3 =  Convert.ToDateTime(test2[1]);
```

Pero la parte de la que me deshago al hacer un split tendrá algún significado...

¿Alguien sabe que tipo de fecha es esta? ¿o como hacer la conversion de string a datetime sin hacer una chapuza como la del split?

Gracias

Saludos,

Comment: Creo que es ISO 8601 expandido https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese es el formato ISO 8601 el cual posee informacion geografica adicional a la fecha y hora con el objetivo de que puedas identificar la zona horaria donde se capturo la fecha.

En c# para obtener un DateTime podrias hacer algo como:

```
using System.Globalization;

DateTime test;
DateTime.TryParseExact(
       "2020-11-05:21:38+21:38",
       "s",
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
       DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out test);
```